# List this PSCustomObject as a Table

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I made a short "quick and dirty" PS-Script that compares two folders which sould normaly have the same files in it. So i use the `Get-FileHash`Function to compare all Files.

I have an PSCustomObject in which all checks are documented. At the end i want to write this PSCustomObject as a Table to the console. But i don't get it...

This is my Object:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> $statushash | Get-Member


   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition                       
----        ----------   ----------                       
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)   
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()                
GetType     Method       type GetType()                   
ToString    Method       string ToString()                
Check       NoteProperty Object[] Check=System.Object[]   
FileSrv1    NoteProperty Object[] FileSrv1=System.Object[]
FileSrv2    NoteProperty Object[] FileSrv2=System.Object[]
Hash1       NoteProperty Object[] Hash1=System.Object[]   
Hash2       NoteProperty Object[] Hash2=System.Object[]

PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> $statushash


FileSrv1 : {GPT.INI, comment.cmtx, Registry.pol, fdeploy.ini...}
FileSrv2 : {GPT.INI, comment.cmtx, Registry.pol, fdeploy.ini...}
Hash1    : {AC88A2F34AB6BE659F511ACB1B8AB74B61CC64F5DB4B5DE384D51C7ABBDBC959, E0A3EC4393A1EDD1A5EB8D1E640DCE2F1BE0C2C33B6753A82C937EDDEC0C75C7, 
           C5D6108E5CDE1823AA63D333F2D178C00E0F69613F71CFFB7D12779A5810B320, 5AD8F52071D25165E7E68064AB194EC27A074A3846149ED0689AF23E7F7F2D00...}
Hash2    : {AC88A2F34AB6BE659F511ACB1B8AB74B61CC64F5DB4B5DE384D51C7ABBDBC959, E0A3EC4393A1EDD1A5EB8D1E640DCE2F1BE0C2C33B6753A82C937EDDEC0C75C7, 
           C5D6108E5CDE1823AA63D333F2D178C00E0F69613F71CFFB7D12779A5810B320, 5AD8F52071D25165E7E68064AB194EC27A074A3846149ED0689AF23E7F7F2D00...}
Check    : {True, True, True, True...}
```

What i want is a table like i can get using gci (for example):

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> gci | Select Name, Mode, Extension, Attributes

Name                          Mode   Extension Attributes
----                          ----   --------- ----------
de                            d-----            Directory
de-DE                         d-----            Directory
Examples                      d-----            Directory
Modules                       d-----            Directory
Schemas                       d-----            Directory
SessionConfig                 d-----            Directory
Certificate.format.ps1xml     -a---l .ps1xml      Archive
Diagnostics.Format.ps1xml     -a---l .ps1xml      Archive
DotNetTypes.format.ps1xml     -a---l .ps1xml      Archive
Event.Format.ps1xml           -a---l .ps1xml      Archive
FileSystem.format.ps1xml      -a---l .ps1xml      Archive
```

I tried it already with `$hashstatus | Format-Table` or with `$statushash | Select -expand *` But it doesn't work.

Sorry for this stupid question but i am not a PS pro and i really don't get it... Thank you in advance for your help!

**EDIT:**
Here is the part where i initialized the Custom Object:

```
$statushash = New-Object PSCustomObject
    $statushash | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -name FileSrv1 -Value @()
    $statushash | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -name FileSrv2 -Value @()
    $statushash | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -name Hash1 -Value @()
    $statushash | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -name Hash2 -Value @()
    $statushash | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -name Check -Value @()
```

Comment: Have you tried $hashstatus | format-table *    ?

Comment: Hi David. yes i tried. i don't get any result if i do this: `PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> $hashstatus | format-table *

PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> ` Maybe i used the wrong data types for my issue...

Comment: @frupfrup you have arrays inside properties; you would need an array of pscustom objects in order to be shown properly by format-table. What is your script?

Comment: Can you show us *how* you constructed the `$statushash` object in the first place? As @AntonKruglov mentions, you've stuffed all of your data into a single object

Comment: You should rewrite the function to create an array of Objects, one per file which has Filename, Server1Hash, Server2Hash and Check properties..

Comment: Hi Guys, i added this part. Ok. I think i understand what i made wrong... an array of objects makes sense... yeah... i can't think like an programmer ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments i rewrote this part. As Frode F. said i made an array of PSCustomObject's:

```
$statushash = @()

function comparefile ($file1, $file2){

   $erg = New-Object PSCustomObject
    $erg | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -name FileSrv1 -Value $file1.Name
    $erg | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -name Hash1 -Value (Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 $file1.Fullname | select -Expand Hash)
    $erg | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -name FileSrv2 -Value $file2.Name
    $erg | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -name Hash2 -Value (Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 $file2.Fullname | select -Expand Hash)
    $erg | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -name Check -Value $false

    if($erg.hash1 -eq $erg.hash2){
        $erg.check = $true
    }
    else{
        $erg.check = $false
    }
    return $erg     
}

for ([...]){
    $statushash += comparefile $List1[$i] $List2[$i]
}

$statushash | Format-Table *
```

Works now. Thank you.